# Wifi driver not working properly dell inspiron 1525

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, inspiron

I tried just installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a colleague's Dell inspiron 1525 who wasn't happy with his previous os...

I tried to install the basic driver, with

```
$sudo apt-get install bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Nevertheless, I can't access anything with it. No wifi, I can't neither enable-disable it using the switch on the right of the laptop. The blue led of the wifi is also of.

(2) I then tried, after having looked at the issue all over the internet, to purge the `bcmwl-kernel-source`, install `firmware-b43-installer`, and then run `$sudo modprobe b43`. (I'm using a wire actually)

This seemed to work at first, and the hardware switch is fully functional, and the led is on, but I can't see any wifi showing up, either if I look from the terminal or the GUI.

Very interestingly, the computer won't shut down when only the bcmwl-kernel-source is installed (I assume this is not a software or a driver, but I don't really know how to explain otherwise). It stays on the ubuntu logo with the 4 or 5 little dots. It shuts down pretty well after (2).

My wireless card :

> Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:4312]

and I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 32 bits

Of course the version is up-to-date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved the issue after re-installing linux. I must have done something wrong when removing/adding things from the blacklist, following answers on forums.

I then had a new issue, I was locked in the login loop (The guest user desktop was working fine). I could solve this creating a new user (which was for me the easiest solution by far), now everything works fine.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The driver you installed is incorrect. Please open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get purge bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Reboot and check:

```
iwconfig
lsmod | grep b43
rfkill list all
dmesg | grep b43
```

I will refine this answer once I get more information from you.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't mention that it still doesn't work.
It remains the same as before, the wifi led is blue and the hard switch works, but it won't detect any wifi.